# What content types are shown at a search page?

Tags: custom-post-types, search

I have created several custom content types.

My question: What about showing things of different content types in search.php? Are different post types shown in search.php? if not how to make them shown? How should I configure the search code in order to show these content types which I want to show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default it is usually `post`s and `page`s, but, you can modify this several ways

**URLs**

`example.com/?s=test` will search for the term test in posts and pages, but, `example.com/?s=test&post_type=product` will search posts of the type `product` for the term test.

In the same way appending ?s=term to your post type archive URL will search that archive for that term, as it will by appending it to various other URLs

**Query filters**

You can modify the following code to do the post type adjustment automatically without needing the above change:

```
function filter_search($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'page', 'customposttype'));
    };
    return $query;
};
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'filter_search');
```

Some people advise that you add a query_posts line above your post loop in your search template. I advise against this as this means an additional unnecessary database query, and it overrides any filters and hooks that try to add features or improve the search query

**Specific individual Search for individual custom post types**

See here:

http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/template/create-multiple-search-templates-for-custom-post-types/

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this - when you register your post types you need to make sure they are not excluded from search - exclude_from_search=true.

Then you need to add the post_type to your search loop. To do so you can add a filter to your search query by placing this in functions.php:

```
function filter_search($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
    $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'YOUR POST TYPE'));
    };
    return $query;
};
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'filter_search');
```

This search will only return posts and YOUR POST TYPE, no pages or whatnot.